# multiple draggables are always moving once item is dragged

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, dragtarget

My goal is to have a dog as my `DragTarget` and multiple items I can drag to the dog.
Whenever I drag one item the others are switching positions.
Also when I drag the item onto the `DragTarget` I want to print out a text in a text-box - but nothing is executed even though I'm using `onAccept`.

This is the code I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prototype/screens/start-page.dart';

class DragDropItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const DragDropItems({super.key});
  final Color color = Colors.black;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/Environment.png'))),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
                    child: DragTarget<String>(
                      onAccept: (data) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: 'asdf',
                                      hintText: 'gang'),
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      builder: (_, __, ___) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 300,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/Doggo3.png'),
                        );
                      },
                    ))),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Draggable<String>(
                          data: 'red',
                          feedback: SizedBox(
                              height: 90.0,
                              width: 90.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/cupcake1.png'),
                              )),
                          childWhenDragging: Container(),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 90.0,
                            width: 90.0,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Image.asset('assets/images/cupcake1.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Draggable<String>(
                          data: 'blue',
                          feedback: SizedBox(
                              height: 90.0,
                              width: 90.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Image.asset('assets/images/banana1.png'),
                              )),
                          childWhenDragging: Container(),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 90.0,
                            width: 90.0,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Image.asset('assets/images/banana1.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Draggable<String>(
                          data: 'green',
                          feedback: SizedBox(
                              height: 90.0,
                              width: 90.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child:
                                    Image.asset('assets/images/hamburger1.png'),
                              )),
                          childWhenDragging: Container(),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 90.0,
                            width: 90.0,
                            child: Center(
                              child:
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/hamburger1.png'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )))
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

this is the result when executing on the emulator:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNoIy.png)

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the widget passed to the **child** parameter for **childWhenDragging** also. It is not required for both to be the same. You can use any widget.

Check this article: **https://blog.logrocket.com/drag-and-drop-ui-elements-in-flutter-with-draggable-and-dragtarget/**